# Why does this function run faster with long numbers than short numbers?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I wrote a JS perf to show that parsing the digits in a number via magnitude reduction is faster than by string evaluation (for a sorting task). What I found though is that the magnitude reduction algorithm performs operations faster for longer numbers (not per digit, but in total), even though it should loop more times for those longer numbers. It happens in Chrome, Safari and Firefox on OS X (haven't tested other OSs).

Any Idea what's going on here?

Here's the perf: http://jsperf.com/get-digits-from-integer

**Edit** Here's a perf that shows the differences with varying numbers of digits 8, 16, 32, 64, and 128. Only the 8-digit number is slower than expected, at 16-digits, the performance slows down as the numbers get longer. http://jsperf.com/get-digits-from-integer/3

and here's the function in question:

```
function getDigitsByMagnitudeReduction(num){
  var digits = [];
  while (num > 0){
    digits.push(num % 10);
    num = (num / 10) >> 0;
  }
  return digits.reverse();
}
```

Comment: your long numbers are too long...

Comment: I think the [safeness of numbers in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) heavily interferes here.

Comment: [_Shifts a in binary representation b (< 32) bits to the right, discarding bits shifted off._](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators). Your shift operation ends up being 0, so you only process 1 digit for those very long numbers

Comment: Take a look at what `(veryLongNum/10) >> 0` returns

Comment: just use `num.toString().split("")` next time

Comment: @dandavis , the end result needs to be an array of ints, but disregard that for the moment and only look at the first result

Comment: @dandavis, toString wouldn't work as if its a very large number like OP is using it would be converted to exponential notation ie `9.188275911029288e+61` before the split

Comment: @PatrickGunderson: ok, try `12344 .toString().split("").map(Math.floor)`

Comment: @PatrickEvans: agreed, but neither would any other Number-based approach...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before checking the performance of a function, you should check that it actually returns the correct result.

You are using `>> 0` to truncate a number to an integer. The bitwise operations work with 32 bits numbers, so the function will only work with numbers up to `21474836479`.

If you use `num = Math.floor((num / 10));` it will work with larger numbers, but the precision of numbers in JavaScript is limited to 15-17 digits, so neither the result for `91827766102983847569298376298387839` nor for `91882759110292883726299387440027766102983847569298376298387839` will be correct.

Comment: And the performance boost is because `(veryLongNum / 10) >> 0` is `0`, so the loop stops after 1 iteration.

Comment: OK, any idea why the performance degrades even further for very very long numbers?

Comment: @PatrickGunderson: For any input value larger than `21474836479` the result of the bitwise operation is zero, so you end up with a single item in the array (as Barmar showed above). Up to that number the performance will depend on the number of digits, but after that the result is a single item array, and the execution time drops.

Comment: @guffa, after that threshold, execution time still increases the longer the number gets.

Comment: @PatrickGunderson: That's not the result that I see. http://jsperf.com/get-digits-from-integer/3